# Hystrix turbine is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, hystrix, turbine

I am configuring hystrix turbine dashbord using ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery . When I hit normal stream URL, it works fine
http://localhost:8080/turbine.stream?cluster=EXAMPLE

[image]

But when I try to load this cluster stream in dashbord it show below error "unnable to connect command matrix" on browser and on console "EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/plain") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.". Please have look on screen shot.

[image]

Below is my config.properties

```
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=EXAMPLE,EXAMPLE1
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix=:9080/hystrix.stream

turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.EXAMPLE.instances=localhost
turbine.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery.EXAMPLE1.instances=139.126.244.170

InstanceDiscovery.impl=com.netflix.turbine.discovery.ConfigPropertyBasedDiscovery
```

My Application.java

```
    @EnableHystrixDashboard
    public class Application extends SpringBootApplication {

        private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
            TurbineInit.init();
        }

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            super.configure(application);
            return application.sources(applicationClass);
        }

    }

And servlet registration for "/turbine.stream"

    @Configuration
    public class ServletRegistrationConfig {
        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean registerTurbineBean(){
            return  new ServletRegistrationBean(new TurbineStreamServlet(), "/turbine.stream");
        }
    }
```

Please assist me in this. And let me know if I missed out in configuration.

Comment: This has been resolved, proxy.stream was not working because application's internal restrictions but now its working as  proxy.stream is working.

Comment: Hi, it seems I run into similar issue. Could you please let me know how to make proxy stream work?

Comment: exclude proxy stream from authentication if you have,  or check if you have enabled any filter which holds the response.

Comment: @Rakesh - I followed all your suggestions still its giving the same version.. I am using Spring Boot version 2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: @Sayali sorry for late reply.. but have you checked you stream URLs are not skipped from security filters?

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431036/spring-boot-v2-2-6-release-and-turbine-unable-to-aggregate-the-metrix?