# Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE and Turbine - Unable to aggregate the metrix

Tags: spring, hystrix, turbine, hystrix-dashboard

I am working on **Spring Boot v2.2.6.RELEASE + Eureka + Hystrix and Turbine**. Before posting this question I went through many links like:

- [Spring Boot Turbine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51615494/spring-boot-turbine)
- [Spring Boot + Eureka Server + Hystrix with Turbine: empty turbine.stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28365202/spring-boot-eureka-server-hystrix-with-turbine-empty-turbine-stream)
- [Turbine Dashboard Is not Loading for Aggregation in Spring Cloud Microservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47657427/turbine-dashboard-is-not-loading-for-aggregation-in-spring-cloud-microservice)

But neither solution worked for me.

application.properties

```
server.port=8085
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins=true

#turbine settings
turbine.app-config=tollrate-billboard,fastpass-console
turbine.aggregator.clusterConfig=TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD,FASTPASS-CONSOLE
turbine.cluster-name-expression= new String("default")
turbine.combine-host-port=true
turbine.instanceUrlSuffix.default=/hystrix.stream
```

CoHystrixDashboardApplication.java

```
@EnableTurbine
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@SpringBootApplication
public class CoHystrixDashboardApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CoHystrixDashboardApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Even If I hit url many times : `http://localhost:8082/customerdetails?fastpassid=101`, the aggregate details are not coming to the Hystrix.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>co-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>co-hystrix-dashboard</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--  Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hystrix Dashboard -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Turbine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>
                spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine
            </artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have this demo project (just this project) up on github so I can run it and debug your issue?

Comment: Hey I've uploaded whole code here: https://github.com/JavaNeed/spring-cloud-hystrix-turbine. Could you please guide me ?

Comment: @storesource - Could you pls help me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61444872/org-springframework-cloud-netflix-hystrix-dashboard-hystrixdashboardconfiguratio.

Please gude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using below changes -

I had to remove `management.endpoints.web.base-path=/` from **`fastpass-console`** and `tollrate-billboard`.

Now when I hit: `http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=TOLLRATE-BILLBOARD`, I am getting details here -

[image]

Now when I hit: `**http://localhost:8085/turbine.stream?cluster=FASTPASS-CONSOLE**`, I am getting details here -

[image]